# MongoDB high storageSize

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

I've just switched from mysql to work with mongoDB and it's pretty awesome but I'm struggling with the db datasize..

I have about 700 documents per day, and each has about 900 comments embeddeds inside.

The average object size is about 53k (this is only with a couple of hours), so with easy maths it should be 53*700 = 37MB. But the total size is about 250MB (storageSize) (only 2h!)

So, I'll create more than 1GB of data every day, in mysql was about 100mb/day (even less).

is this normal? How can I deal with it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How often are you updating the documents with comments? What operator do you use?

Comment: One embed per minute with update and $push inside a comments{} array. So it's about 700 embeds per minute (there's 1440 minutes in a day, but it's not working 24h that's why it's about 900embeds per doc). Thanks!

Comment: Yeah your probably getting the "siwss cheese" effect, basically your suffering from fragmentation, you can solve this problem either running a repairdatabase or changing your schema to factor out the comments.

Comment: True, with repairdatabase it goes down from 350mb to 50mb. and the objectsize * objects = storagesize. But after 20minutes, it gets wrong again... (could be fixed with repairdatabase, but I don't think this is the way!)any ideas? :)

Comment: The only way is with a schema change, MongoDB uses single contigeous pieces of hard disk space to store documents on so that it only one single hard disk access to get it, unfortunately this does mean that a constantly growing document will constantly move creating fragmentation, the only way around is to change how your app works

Comment: uhm understood. And is there any way to book space for each document? That would solve the fragmentation problem, right?

Comment: You can add the paddingof2sizes option to the collection but I don't think it will work here but I suppose you could try: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/

Comment: But to answer another part of your question, no: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1810

Comment: I tried the paddingof2sizes but like you said, it doesn't work :( 
I could create another collection and create one doc for each comment with a relational id, but then, requesting 1 thousand docs could be very slow...

Comment: Nah that should be super sonic, like the hedgehog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing this is because of fragmentation of record objects.

Each document within MongoDB is held within an internal record object, think of it as a C++ struct which represents a document.

Record objects are single contiguous pieces of hard disk space, so as to limit the number of hard disk look-ups and make them sequential. This hard disk look-up has a nasty down side though, if are constantly growing your documents then they must constantly be moved to larger and larger record objects, sending the old record objects to the `$freelists` (an internal list of free spaces) to be used by another object of that size that comes in.

This creates fragmentation, I believe this is what you are seeing with your own data.

One way to solve this normally is to use `powerof2sizes` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/ ), unfortunately due to how your document increases I do not think this will work.

Another way to solve this would be to manually set the padding so that the document always fits and never moves however you cannot yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1810

The best way, currently, to solve this problem is to change your schema to factor out the comments into their own collection.

This does mean two queries but they should be two indexed super fast queries, maybe a couple of microseconds slower than loading that document from disk.

Comment: So, create a collection for the comments and create a document for each comment? Would it be fast enough if every day it creates about 1M docs? Thanks!

Comment: @Ksakser Yeah it should be

Answer (score 0):

incase of planning to change schema, visit http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports to avoid data grow and fragmentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I haven't seen in any of the current answers is document padding on initial insert.  You can avoid the data growth (to some extent) by "padding" the documents with some extra space at the beginning to accommodate the comments that will be added in the future.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-manual-padding

Using the data you already have on hand about your average document size, add a little bit to that and on your initial insert, include that padding. It should improve your update performance as well as avoid the swiss cheese effect the commenters above are talking about.

For reference, this is why you are seeing so much extra space:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/